# How to update records based on records in new files spark scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have folders for each day and it got files which are updated. I have to read all files in using spark scala and get only latest records from the files.

Folder 1- transactionData/20220401/ Files

File abc-

| Month | Year | TransactionId | Product | Price | Qty | LastModifiedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022 | 123 | soap | 100 | 2 | 20220401 |
| 3 | 2022 | 1234 | shampoo | 250 | 1 | 20220401 |
| 3 | 2022 | 12345 | oil | 80 | 1 | 20220401 |
| 4 | 2022 | 123456 | perfume | 300 | 1 | 20220401 |

File xyz -

| Month | Year | TransactionId | Product | Price | Qty | LastModifiedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022 | 1234567 | soap | 150 | 3 | 20220401 |
| 4 | 2022 | 12345678 | hair gel | 260 | 1 | 20220401 |
| 4 | 2022 | 123456789 | perfume | 600 | 2 | 20220401 |

Folder 2- transactionData/20220402/ Files

File xyz-

| Month | Year | TransactionId | Product | Price | Qty | LastModifiedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022 | 1234567 | soap | 50 | 1 | 20220402 |
| 4 | 2022 | 12345678 | hair gel | 260 | 1 | 20220402 |

as you can see in tables above folder 1 got 2 files and folder 2 has 1 file i.e xyz which is updated file from folder 1. in xyz file Transcation Id - 123456789 got deleted and Transcation Id - 12345678 got modified.

I want result Like below Dataframe,

| Month | Year | TransactionId | Product | Price | Qty | LastModifiedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022 | 123 | soap | 100 | 2 | 20220401 |
| 3 | 2022 | 1234 | shampoo | 250 | 1 | 20220401 |
| 3 | 2022 | 12345 | oil | 80 | 1 | 20220401 |
| 4 | 2022 | 123456 | perfume | 300 | 1 | 20220401 |
| 4 | 2022 | 1234567 | soap | 50 | 1 | 20220402 |
| 4 | 2022 | 12345678 | hair gel | 260 | 1 | 20220402 |

I tried with partition by Month, Year, TransactionId, order by LastmodifiedDate and used Dense rank funciton to get latest records. but it only gave modified records. deleted records didn't removed.

how to get the results above?

Comment: Take a look to Structured Stream InputSource: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez I am not using spark streaming here, I need to solve it through batch processing only

Comment: Would make more sense to just not read in the old xyz file. If everything is combined there isn't an easy way to know which rows need to get deleted.

Comment: @Sentinel problem is there will be so many date wise folders and so many files in those folders. So its hard to know which one to pic and which one to not